# R - How to run a GWAS analysis with no position data?

Tags: r, gwas

everyone!

I am trying to run a GWAS analysis in R on some very simple genetic data. It only contains the SNPs and one outcome variable (as well as an ID variable for each observation).

Everything I have found online includes chromosome and position data. I have that for the SNPs, but in a separate file. (My plan is to map the SNPs after the relevant ones have been selected).

How can I go about running a GWAS analysis on this data? Would I need to, or could I use another method to filter to only the most significant SNPs?

I tried this, but it didn't work, because my data is not a gData object.

```
# SNPs are in A/B notation, with 0 = AA, 1 = AB, and 2 = BB

library(statgenGWAS)

id <- c("person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", "person5", "person6", "person7", "person8", "person9", "person10")
snp1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
snp2 <- c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
snp3 <- c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2)
diagnosis <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, snp1, snp2, snp3, diagnosis))

gwas1a <- runSingleTraitGwas(gData = data,
                             traits = "diagnosis")
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Where does the `runSingleTraitGwas` come from? Does it require a position? Please list any non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: @MrFlick Oops, thank you for mentioning that. I had it in the code, but I accidentally deleted it when I added the reproducible example data. It was from the statgenGWAS package. I have added it to the code now.